# Laravel 5.2 eloquent mutator for field with multiple entries.

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So basically I have an array mutator which works perfectly, but the field its pulling is only a char 1 and only 1 entry so it works fine

However I want to do the exact same thing with a field that contains multiple entries by a comma separator. below is what i have that works and and example of what I want.

The field interests contains a number from 1 to 3,

```
protected $userTypes = array(
    '1' => 'Owner',
    '2' => 'Admin',
    '3' => 'Standard User'
);

public function getUserTypeAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->userTypes[$value];
}
```

now I have another field lets call it, InterestList but it has multiple entries separated by commas like so 3,4,5,6,7

How would I get the code like above to work for something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this --

```
<?php

// lets define the interest list

protected $interestList = array(
    '1' => 'Play',
    '2' => 'Sing',
    '3' => 'Hobby'
);


// function for getting the interesttype strings
public function getIntestetTypeString($intStr=''){
    // $intStr = '1,3' ; may be something like
    $interestList = '';
    if(!empty($intStr)){
        $attrToIterate = explode(", ",$intStr) ;

        foreach($attrToIterate as $value){
            if($interestList){
                $interestList .= ','. $this->interestList[$value] ;
            }else{
                $interestList .=  $this->interestList[$value] ;
            }   
        }
    }

    return $interestList ;
}
```

Comment: Wow you are amazing. I have no tried it yet but it totally makes sense!!! Thank you. I will try it thrn upvote

Comment: Hey So i Have implemented this however it returns nothing, just curious, on the blade how do i return this? I am doing    {{ $UserDetails->IntestetType }}

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I ended up with an answer, Below is the code

```
public function getInterestsAttribute($value)
{
    $InterestList = array(
        '1' => 'Books',
        '2' => 'Cars',
        '3' => 'Cats'
    );

    $strExplode = explode(",",$value);
    foreach ($strExplode as $i=>$ANUMBER){
        echo $InterestList[$ANUMBER];
    }

}
```

Then in the blade you just go about your way as normal.  eg.

{{ $UserProfile->Interests }}